# Calling public event to trigger method in another class in C#

Tags: c#, events

I wanted to ask if this is Event possible in C#. I have not much worked with Events till now.

Say I have a class A which subscribed to a FormClosing Event of a form:

```
public class A
{
   private void f_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
   {
     //Now here a public Event should be called
   }
}
```

Now there I want a public Event to be called. Let's say now I have another class B which has a certain method.

```
public class B
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
  }
}
```

Now what I want to do:

A Form gets closed so class A is getting notified. There, a public Event gets triggered (which is somewhere in a public class). I want to subscribe my method in class B to this Event so it gets called when that happens. Is this possible? And how is the syntax? I haven't found something useful till now.

Edit: I can't create an instance of class B directly from class A.

Comment: I could answer this question but I feel that you're not realistic when you say that you've not found something useful on the net. Events have been in C# since its inception so there articles about the topic since more than 15 years.

Comment: Yes I know. All I found is how to trigger Events when creating an instance of class B in class A. I've read a lot but still have trouble. Please help me :/

Comment: I really believe that you want us to save up your time and get a summary. There're tons of articles about events. Just use Google to search these keywords: "c# events codeproject" and see what happens...

Comment: No. I tried around a lot so I ended up asking here. My problem is that I can not create an instance of class B in class A. Tried to make a public delegate but ended up that I didn't know how to subscribe correctly class B's class to this delegate

Comment: So show us the code then.

Answer (score 3):

Its possible .

1. Create a new event in A.
2. Raise the event within the eventhandler `f_FormClosed`
3. Subscribe to this event in B.
4. Within the eventhandler in B call the method `DoSomething`

For the syntax part you could check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

```
// A delegate type for hooking up change notifications.
  public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

 // A class that works just like ArrayList, but sends event
 // notifications whenever the list changes.
 public class ListWithChangedEvent: ArrayList 
 {
    // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever the
    // elements of the list change.
    public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

    // Invoke the Changed event; called whenever list changes
    protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e) 
    {
      if (Changed != null)
       //you raise the event here.
        Changed(this, e);
    }
 }
```

Now in your other class do something like this

```
  class EventListener 
   {
     private ListWithChangedEvent List;

      public EventListener(ListWithChangedEvent list) 
      {
        List = list;
        // Add "ListChanged" to the Changed event on "List".
        //This is how we subscribe to the event created in ListWithChangedEvent class
        List.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
      }

     // This will be called whenever the list changes.
     private void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     {
      Console.WriteLine("This is called when the event fires.");
     }
 }
```

Comment: How is the syntax? I have problems getting this together somehow.

Comment: Check this example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Conax see the EDIT to how to subscribe to the event

Comment: This does not work because I can't pass an instance of class A to class B in the constructor. The instance of class B is created by another class.

Comment: it doesnt matter who creates your instance . you need an instance of class A to subscribe to its event .

Comment: But I don't got one. The instance gets created by another class and is active somewhere. So this is the Problem here. When it gets created somewhere I would need to Register to a public Event or something. And call this public Event then from another class

Comment: .Try to do the subscription at the place where the instance gets created.you need to show the code  to help me understand

Comment: Solved it with a Singleton class! Thanks for the help :)